# qooxdoo : How to popup a Window that covers whole screen?

Tags: qooxdoo

How to popup a Window that covers whole screen ?

I have the following code:

**Application.js**

```
this.__panel = new myApp.MyPanel();
this.__panel.open();
```

**MyPanel.js**

```
qx.Class.define("myApp.MyPanel",
{
  extend : qx.ui.window.Window,

    construct : function()
    {
      this.base(arguments, "My Panel");
      // adjust size
      this.setWidth(800);
      this.setHeight(480);
    }
});
```

Instead of 800 x 480, I would like the Window to be open in full screen, without Title and close button. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `maximize` method to set the window to full screen. But that will still show the caption bar containing the buttons. Depending on what you want, you can hide / disable each of the buttons. If you don't want the caption bar at all, I would simply add the content of the window to the root of you app.

Comment: `maximize()` is better than my answer, as it handles browser resizes automatically.

Answer (score 1):

To cover the whole screen, use the following lines:

```
this.setWidth(qx.bom.Viewport.getWidth());
this.setHeight(qx.bom.Viewport.getHeight());
```

Don't forget to handle browser resizing !

Also, to hide the title bar, add this line:

```
this.getChildControl("captionbar").setVisibility("excluded");
```